# "Error: write EPIPE" with Socket.io on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, serverside-javascript

**I manually applied this patch and everything works now. Waiting on upstream to fix this**
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/pull/361/files

---

I'm just trying to follow the examples given and trying to get this to work.

Mockserver.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('+ new client');
    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('- lost a client');
    });
});
```

Mockclient.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = new io.connect('localhost', { port: 8000 });

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});

socket.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I then run these pair with node Mockserver.js and node Mockclient.js on another terminal

```
   info  - socket.io started
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 14797776461130411158
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/14797776461130411158
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 14797776461130411158
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
+ new client
   debug - set close timeout for client 14797776461130411158
   ***************************** error occurs here ****************
   info  - socket error Error: write EPIPE
   at errnoException (net.js:632:11)
   at Object.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:470:18)
   ****************************************************************
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/14797776461130411158?t=1325912082073
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client 14797776461130411158
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 14797776461130411158
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   info  - transport end
   debug- set close timeout for client 14797776461130411158
   debug - cleared close timeout for client 14797776461130411158
```

at this point I stopped Mockclient.js

```
- lost a client
   debug - discarding transport
```

The only output for "node Mockclient.js" is

```
The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.
```

What's causing the socket exception? I'm probably missing something pretty obvious. Also, can somebody else try my code to see if the errors on their machine as well? The code inside socket.on('connect'... isn't triggering either. I don't exactly know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply this patch 
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/pull/361/files

Comment: After patching, I got the following error: module.js:332 throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'"); ^
Error: Cannot find module 'ws' Any ideas?

Comment: @MartinKapfhammer you probably want to do a `npm install -g ws`